# How do I prevent duplicate materials when copying between instances?

Tags: materials

I have two instances of Blender open. One instance has a bunch of common objects that I am using to build a model (doors, walls, props, etc). I can copy, for example, a door into the other instance. Then if I need another door model that is using the same material as the first one I copied, it will create a duplicate material for that door.

Is there a way to prevent this? What I need is ALT-D (linked object) but for going between instances. Otherwise I end up with alot of this:

[image]

Thoughts?

Comment: The question is: Why would you do that? If you open the same file twice, you have an instance, but what to do with it? At some point, you have to save both files, so you have *two files* in the end. And with two files, what speaks against using standard linking? Am I missing something here?

Comment: Sorry if this is unclear. I'm not opening the same file twice. I have one file that is filled with objects. I then open ANOTHER instance of Blender. So now there are two separate Blender windows running. I copy objects in from the first one, and duplicate materials are created if they already exist.

Comment: Aah, so like in 3ds Max - if merging objects, it will detect that another material with the same name is in the scene, and ask what to do. Use the old material for both objects, the new one, or create a copy.
Or, like in After Effects, some functionality to consolidate footage - or in this case identical materials apart from name. Sorry, I don't know how to do that, but I guess it would be possible using scripting.